# Shutdown of applications running on the IIS server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server application which when running on the server is reset by this error:
Application: w3wp.exe CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2523.51912 .NET Version: 6.0.25 Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFA26839062 (00007FFA265A0000) with exit code 8013135e.
I have not found any information about this error, maybe here someone can tell me what this error means, how to solve it or where to look for more information about it.

Comment: If you could provide the following information in your question, might help people answering it. Is that a new app or an existing app that ran fine before and now throws the error after changes were made? Is that app the only [blazor] app running on that server that throws the error or are there other [blazor] apps running on that server that also throw the error? What version of IIS?

Comment: This is a new app,
There is only this app on the server,
I am not able to check now what version of IIS it is

Comment: This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this, so you can try to debug the cause using IIS [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.